# how to assign derive value to array inside FOR LOOP

Tags: php, arrays

How to I assign the output/derived value to array inside FOR LOOP

```
$num = count($email);
  for($i=0; $i < $num; $i++){
      $result = do_post_request("http://api.mysite/api/IsActiveAccount?email=". $email[$i], null);
      $status = str_replace('{"result":', "", $result);
      $status = str_replace('}', "", $status);
      echo  $email[$i] ;
   }

OUTPUT---->
  red@yahoo.com
  blue@yahoo.com
  yellow@yahoo.com
  white@yahoo.com
```

How do I assign/place that inside array? Like this one.

```
  $value = array("red@yahoo.com","blue@yahoo.com","yellow@yahoo.com", "white@yahoo.com")
```

Comment: You know `$status` is never used right?

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇ ƇhƐȓ0nè ill assign both of them to array just for demo but i need $status and $email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to assign `$email[$i]` to `$value` as like

```
for($i=0; $i < $num; $i++){
  $result = do_post_request("http://api.mysite/api/IsActiveAccount?email=". $email[$i], null);
  $status = str_replace('{"result":', "", $result);
  $status = str_replace('}', "", $status);
  $value[] = $email[$i] ;    // Here it will assign $email in $value as an array 
}
print_r($value);
```

Comment: @Gautam we both had same answer so deleted mine. BTW you forgot to initialize `$value`. place `$value=array();` before the `for` loop.

Comment: I thought that he already initialized it as an array....BTW No need to initialize as an array.If we assign like with [] then it will be considered as an array , I think

Comment: @Gautam3164 i need 8mins to mark your answer correct thank you guys :D

Comment: @Gautam3164 if you don't initialize and `$num` is less than 1, you get a warning

Comment: @Gautam3164 Can i used that in mySQL directly? the array? Like "SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email NOT IN ('.$value.')" correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: Yes you can but the format should be like NOT IN (1,2,3).Means $value = (1,2,3,..).You need to do like $val = implode(',',$value) and then use it in `IN`

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = array();

for($i=0; $i < $num; $i++){

 $result = do_post_request("http://api.mysite/api/IsActiveAccount?email=". $email[$i], null);
$status = str_replace('{"result":', "", $result);
$status = str_replace('}', "", $status);
$value[] = $email[$i] ;

}

print_r($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it JSON?

```
 $values = array();
 for($i=0; $i < $num; $i++){
    $result = do_post_request("http://api.mysite/api/IsActiveAccount?email=". $email[$i], null);
    $result = json_decode($result);
    $values[] = $result['result'];
 }
```

Comment: Code is in PHP but result from that website is in JSON ;)

Comment: @Elon Than Sorry for the OUTPUT: <----- its not json its php